# PropertyGrid value change

Tags: vb.net

I and using VB.bet and have a property grid on a form and I need to know when a piece of text changed.  I added a sub for checking if an input changed and put a break point on the line of code when debugging to make sure it was working on all the subs.

```
PropertyGrid2_PreviewKeyDown
PropertyGrid2_KeyPress
PropertyGrid2_Click
PropertyGrid2_PropertyValueChanged1
```

It seems like the only time I get a value changed if there is a combo list on a selection, but can't get VS2019 to break on the other three.  Pressing a key does not break if I enter text on one of the text controls.  There are about 22 inputs in it with input methods from combo to text.
This control has been in the program a long time, so how can I make sure it is the latest version of .net or does it automatically update when I assign a .net version in the project properties?

Placing breakpoints in other built-in functions to trap user input and it never broke at those points so it is difficult for me to tell if the function is working, when other controls work just fine.

```
PropertyGrid2_PreviewKeyDown
PropertyGrid2_KeyPress
PropertyGrid2_Click
PropertyGrid2_PropertyValueChanged1
```

```
Private Sub PropertyGrid2_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles PropertyGrid2.PreviewKeyDown
    'didn't work for trapping key entry
    Dim x As String = ""
    x = x'break point here to see if it traps
End Sub

Private Sub PropertyGrid2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PropertyGrid2.KeyPress
    'didn't work for trapping key entry
    Dim x As String = ""
    x = x'break point here to see if it traps
End Sub

Private Sub PropertyGrid2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PropertyGrid2.Click
    'didn't work for trapping key entry
    Dim x As String = ""
    x = x'break point here to see if it traps
End Sub

Private Sub PropertyGrid2_PropertyValueChanged1(s As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PropertyValueChangedEventArgs) Handles PropertyGrid2.PropertyValueChanged
    Dim x As Integer = 0'break point here to see if it traps
    'this traps but only on a combo box change, I need text change trapping too
```

***I never get traps at any expected stops.***

Comment: I just tested a `ProperyGrid` with a class with one `String` property and one my own `Enum` and I saw the `PropertyValueChanged` event raised for both.  In the case of the `String` property, the event is not raised until the change is committed to the underlying object, which occurs when you hit `Enter` or navigate to another cell.  Until then, you can hit `Escape` and cancel the change, which is why there's no event.

Comment: I had noticed that I and getting a break-point when I press enter on the text inputs now.  Not sure why it didn't break before.  I could have sworn I pressed enter before.

Comment: I did not get breaks on the other three.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the property KeyPreview is set to true in the form.

Get more info in here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.8